# How do I troubleshoot "simplexml_load_file() parser error: Entity 'nbsp' not defined"?

Tags: php, xml, symbols

I use PHP to generate XML files. I have use some code below to avoid error.

```
$str = str_ireplace(array('<','>','&','\'','"'),array('&lt;','&gt;','&amp;','&apos;','&quot;'),$str);
```

but still cause fault.

```
simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file] *[file name]* parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined in *[file name] [line]*
```

The error text here:

```
Dallas&nbsp;&nbsp;Dallas () is the third-largest city in Texas and the ninth-largest in the United States.
```

In IE8, it seems to fault in `()`. So how many symbols should I notice?

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not defined by default in XML. Maybe is enough to just replace it with a space?

Comment: You say you're using PHP to *generate* XML files; what are you using?  If you're using the right tool it should take care of these entities for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is a HTML entity, but doesn't exist in XML.

Either get rid of it (you're not saying where it comes from, so it's hard to give any more specific advice), or wrap your HTML data in [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) blocks so the parser ignores them.

Comment: so if I use CDATA, Should I still need to use  `str_ireplace`? Thanks.

Comment: @cj333 no, you shouldn't use str_ireplace

Answer (score 6):

HTML specific entities - in this case `&nbsp;` - are not valid xml entities, and that is what simplexml complains about; it reads the file as xml (not html) and finds entities which are not valid. You need to convert HTML entities back to their character representation first (you can use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to do that)

```
$str = "some string containing html";
// this line will convert back html entities to regular characters
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ...);
// now convert special character to their xml entities
$str = str_ireplace(array('<','>','&','\'','"'),array('&lt;','&gt;','&amp;','&apos;','&quot;'),$str);

save_to_xml($str);
```

Note that if you use htmlentities() on your string before saving it in the xml, then that is the source of your problem (as you are converting html character to their respective html entities, which are not recognized by simplexml as xml entities).

```
// this won't work, the html entities it will uses are not valid xml entities
$str = htmlentities($str, ...)

save_to_xml($str);
```

If you have troubles understanding it, think of it as two different languages, like spanish (html) and english (xml), a valid word in spanish ( ) doesn't mean it is also valid in english, no matter the similarities between the two languages.

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp`; is no-breaking space. You have to replace it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 0):

You also may use `htmlentities($str, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES)` ([htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)), which use only XML entities, not HTML (like `&nbsp`, `&ndash`, `&laquo`, `&raquo`, etc.)