# simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 18: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined

Tags: php, html, xml, laravel

My error is: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 18: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined

My problem is that I get this error while reading an xml file from e-commerce site with PHP. Below you can see the xml line where the error is occured.

```
<note><p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün İsmi:</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;">Müzik Kutusu Ses Bombası BS108B</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;'>&nbsp;</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün Hakkında Bilgi:</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;"> - Bluetooth 5.0<br> - Çekim mesafesi: 10m<br> - Kullanım süresi: 3-4 saat<br> - Şarj süresi: 2-3 saat<br> - USB girişi<br> - SD kart girişi<br> - Aux girişi</span></p></note>
```

Can you help me ?

The entire xml:

```
<product>
<stok_id></stok_id>
<stok_adi></stok_adi>
<stok_kodu></stok_kodu>
<stok_key></stok_key>
<liste_fiyati></liste_fiyati>
<fiyat_kdv_dahil></fiyat_kdv_dahil>
<fiyat_kdv_haric></fiyat_kdv_haric>
<fiyat_bayi_satis></fiyat_bayi_satis>
<kdv></kdv>
<doviz></doviz>
<barkod></barkod>
<desi></desi>
<stok_miktari></stok_miktari>
<marka></marka>
<marka_id></marka_id>
<note><p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün İsmi:</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;">Müzik Kutusu Ses Bombası BS108B</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;'>&nbsp;</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün Hakkında Bilgi:</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;"> - Bluetooth 5.0<br> - Çekim mesafesi: 10m<br> - Kullanım süresi: 3-4 saat<br> - Şarj süresi: 2-3 saat<br> - USB girişi<br> - SD kart girişi<br> - Aux girişi</span></p></note>
<category></category>
<kategori_3_id></kategori_3_id>
<kategori_3_adi></kategori_3_adi>
<kategori_2_id></kategori_2_id>
<kategori_2_adi></kategori_2_adi>
<kategori_1_id></kategori_1_id>
<kategori_1_adi></kategori_1_adi>
<fiyat1></fiyat1>
<fiyat1_doviz></fiyat1_doviz>
<fiyat1_kdv></fiyat1_kdv>
<resimler/>
</product>
```

Comment: This is HTML, not XML

Comment: I suppose this is contained in a CDATA section ? Or not ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I troubleshoot "simplexml\_load\_file() parser error: Entity 'nbsp' not defined"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208764/how-do-i-troubleshoot-simplexml-load-file-parser-error-entity-nbsp-not-def)

Comment: I am attaching the whole xml.

Comment: I suspect that it is an xml but inside the content of the notes field some html has been inserted

Comment: https://kosekayalar.com/b2c_xml?key=6ixVFCSWNOO2HnU9Ljct  im working on this xml

Answer (score 1):

The content of `//product[1]/note` element is encoded HTML but it appears on the question as plain HTML.

The problem might be in the source of the document.

Downloading it with `wget` and querying with the mentioned XPath expression. Will give a PHP example also after this.

```
xmllint --xpath '//product[1]/note' tmp.xml
```

Result:

```
<note>&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'&gt;&#xDC;r&#xFC;n &#x130;smi:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: &amp;quot;Open Sans&amp;quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;"&gt;Ks Games 500 Par&#xE7;a Art Gallery Garden Sea Jin Park Puzzle 11377
&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'&gt;&#xDC;r&#xFC;n Hakk&#x131;nda Bilgi:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: &amp;quot;Open Sans&amp;quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;"&gt;(-)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</note>
```

No errors. The content is just a string from XML perspective.

Worth noting that opening the URL on a browser shows the "rendered" content but not the document source

```
<note>
<p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün İsmi:</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;">Ks Games 500 Parça Art Gallery Garden Sea Jin Park Puzzle 11377 </span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;'>&nbsp;</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün Hakkında Bilgi:</span></p> <p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;">(-)</span></p>
</note>
```

PHP7 parses the document without issues but `print_r(), var_dump(), print()` also shows rendered content :-(

```
php7 -r '$xml = simplexml_load_file("tmp.xml"); print($xml->product[0]->note);'
```

Result

```
<p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün İsmi:</span></p>
<p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;">Ks Games 500 Parça Art Gallery Garden Sea Jin Park Puzzle 11377
</span></p>
<p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;'>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p style="margin: 0"><span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'>Ürün Hakkında Bilgi:</span></p>
<p style="margin: 0"><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;">(-)</span></p>
```

Using `SimpleXMLElement::asXML` would show raw content

```
php7 -r '$xml = simplexml_load_file("tmp.xml"); printf("%s\n",$xml->product[0]->note->asXML());'
```

Result:

```
<note>&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'&gt;Ürün İsmi:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: &amp;quot;Open Sans&amp;quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;"&gt;Ks Games 500 Parça Art Gallery Garden Sea Jin Park Puzzle 11377
&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style='font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight:600; color: #1e55fa'&gt;Ürün Hakkında Bilgi:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="margin: 0"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family: &amp;quot;Open Sans&amp;quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #000;"&gt;(-)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</note>
```

Comment: simplexml_load_file() gives an error

Comment: @furkanbozkurt "gives an error" does not help at all. Be more specific if you really want a solution for your problem.